# Looking for an adaptMCMC (R package for adaptive MCMC sampling) tutorial

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian

I need to fit a very complex Bayesian hierarchical model and I want to use the adaptMCMC package of Andreas Scheidegger to do the posterior sampling. I can only find the adaptMCMC package reference manual, which doesn't provide a very helpful example of the core sampling function. Does anyone know if there is a more helpful tutorial out there? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a Bayesian expert. But after looking for such a package, I found WinBUGS, OpenBUGS, JAGS and STAN.
JAGS is a very good one: easier than WinBugs and openbugs and very important it's faster for my model. I try to compute with Stan which seems very powerful, but without succes till now. Jag is very easy to call from R. There are plenty of examples. I found the following blog very powerful:
http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/08/20/using-jags-in-r-with-the-rjags-package/ As I'm new on Bayesian modelling, I'll be happy to hear what you found on your own.

Comment: adaptMCMC is a specific R package. As for other solutions, yeah, I have decided to go with Stan, specifically RStan.